# Target the label of a checked input

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

If I have a radio input that is wrapped within a label, how can I target the label when the input is checked?

```
<div>
  <p>Payment Plan:</p>
  <label><input name="os0" type="radio" value="monthly">TEST</label>
</div>
```

I tried:

```
input:checked + label { color: red }
```

and

```
input:checked + label
```

But none worked, what I am doing wrong? I also tried the `>` selector.

**The reason I have label wrapping the input, is because I NEED the label to be clickable**

Comment: Wrap the text in a span element and do `input:checked + span`.

Answer (score 7):

There's no parent or backward selector in CSS ([yet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)). Thus, we can't select the wrapper label by the wrapped input.

### There are two options:

**1)** Wrapping the content by an inline wrapper like `<span>` element, as follows:

```
<label>
  <input name="os0" type="radio" value="monthly">
  <span>TEST</span>
</label>
```

Then select the `<span>` by using adjacent sibling selector `+`:

```css
input:checked + span {
   color: red
}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsbin.com/gipimeqi/1/edit)**

**2)** Using [`for` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label#Attributes) for the label to target the input by its `id` attribute as follows:

```
<input name="os0" type="radio" id="myinput" value="monthly">
<label for="myinput">TEST</label>
```

And Then select the label by:

```css
input:checked + label {
    color: red
}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsbin.com/dopasoda/2/edit)**.

Comment: But I want the label to be clickable

Answer (score 2):

Your css will work if you modify your html to this:

```
<div>
  <p>Payment Plan:</p>
  <input id="os0" name="os0" type="radio" value="monthly">
  <label for="os0">TEST</label>
</div>
```

Using the `for` attribute with an `id` on the input will let you click on the label to affect the button, as it does when wrapped in the element.

http://jsfiddle.net/PMmrk/